# Do I need to use an older version of Aspose.Cells.dll?

Tags: c#, aspose, .net-framework-version, aspose-cells, assembly-references

I am Asposisizing a legacy app (users complained about the slowness of the code, which is in Excel Interop).

I have added a reference to Aspose.Cells.dll and added this using:

```
using Aspose.Cells;
```

...but get this compile error:

*The type or namespace name 'Aspose' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

Is it because the project's Target framework is set to ".NET Framework 2.0"?

If so, is there an older version of the Aspose.Cells.dll that I can use? Or will I need to increment the target to 4.5?

Here is what I have and what I see:

[image]

So is the problem a mismatch between .NET Frameworks targeted and the Aspose.Cells.dll version?

Comment: had to google "Asposisizing - it said "No results found for Asposisizing" did you instead mean Apostatizing?

Comment: Good one; not exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. The problem is a mismatch between .NET Frameworks.

Answer (score 3):

Seems to be a mismatch between .NET versions.  Ensure that the version of Aspose.Cells was compiled for .NET 2.0.

Otherwise you may need to find an older version of Aspose.Cells that was targeted for that.